# Plus Arithmetic Operation

Tags: javascript, html, math

I've tried use ***Plus Arithmetic Operation*** to calculate 2 input text type number values, but my result was the values are "together", like that:

- Value one: 5
- Value two: 5

**Result**

```
55
```

**Wanted Result**

```
10
```

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function cal(){
    var plus = document.getElementById('plus').value,
        plus1 = document.getElementById('plus1').value;
    var x = plus + plus1;
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    if(result.value == ""){
     result.innerHTML = "?";
    }
    else{
     result.innerHTML = x;
    }
  }
</script>

<input type="text" id="plus" /> + <input type="text" id="plus1" /> = <span id="result"></span>
```

How can I get plus result instead couple of numbers together?

Comment: You need to use ParseInt to parse them as integers. Here you are concatenating 2 strings.

Comment: Do you mind give me an example? I'm not knownledge with that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse them to an Integer type:

```
var x = parseInt(plus) + parseInt(plus1);
```

Then you can use [`isNaN()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) to determine whether it was a valid operation or not: (note that I'm checking the value of `x` not of the resulting output)

```
if(isNaN(x)){
 result.innerHTML = "?";
}
else{
 result.innerHTML = x;
}
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4KB5Y/3/

Comment: I notice when I writing nothing it give me NaN (Not a Number) can I check if the value is not a number and replace it with "?", if it possible please edit your answer.

Comment: Of course, you can make use of the [`isNaN()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) function of Javascript to check it.

Comment: @Yotam sorry  my mistake, you should check `isNaN(x)`, not the input. Im gonna update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
function cal(){
    var plus = +document.getElementById('plus').value,
        plus1 = +document.getElementById('plus1').value;
    var x = plus + plus1;
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    if(isNaN(plus) || isNaN(plus1) || result.value == ""){
     result.innerHTML = "?";
    }
    else{
     result.innerHTML = x;
    }
  }
```

Notice the + signs that convert the two string values to numbers.

Comment: This is currently the only one that correctly converts input values to numbers

Comment: @deceze Where does the OP say they are only accepting *integers*? The example is with 5 and 5, sure, but they are expecting **numbers**. `parseInt` chops off any decimals

Comment: @Ian Fair enough, though I'd expect the OP *does* expect either always floats or always ints. He just doesn't know it himself yet. ;)

Comment: @deceze Another problem with `parseInt` and `parseFloat` is that it strips any non-digits from the end of the string. So if the user typed in `23498asdf`, `parseInt` would parse it as `23498`, which as a developer, I wouldn't want to allow (even if it "cleans up" the user's input). I'm not sure if the OP's code is just an example or something they're actually trying to implement, but the answers that have `parseInt` would be more complete if they included the use of `parseFloat` (which I still wouldn't recommend) and explained the reasoning, or included the `+` conversion (or `Number()`)

Comment: @Ian I'll edit the code to reject NaN as it is probably intended.

Answer (score 2):

```
var plus = parseInt(document.getElementById('plus').value, 10),
    plus1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('plus1').value, 10);
```

This will do what you want.

Comment: Remember to specify the radix.

Comment: Oh yeah , I wil fix it now .

Comment: If you copy-paste from someone else's answer, first make sure their code works.

Answer (score 1):

All values you get from input elements in the DOM are going to be strings.
Javascript uses `+` both for concatenating strings and for addition.
To make it clear you want to *add numbers* instead of concatenating strings, you need to make sure your values are numbers:

```
parseInt(plus, 10) + parseInt(plus1, 10)
```

Yes, this is one of the most basic and often encountered gotchas in Javascript.

Comment: Note that it's pretty important to include the radix `10` here, lest you get surprising results in the wrong base for some inputs.

Comment: Also do note @Ian's comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614374/plus-arithmetic-operation/18614471?noredirect=1#comment27400276_18614471).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both plus and plus1 in parseInt() so you add instead of concatenate.

```
var plus = parseInt( document.getElementById('plus').value ),
    plus1 = parseInt( document.getElementById('plus1').value );
```

Answer (score 0):

parseInt is what missing from your code .. you need to parse it as integer barring which just the concatenation operation takes place , so you can either do this

```
var plus = parseInt(document.getElementById('plus').value, 10),
plus1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('plus1' ).value, 10);
```

or

```
var x = parseInt(plus , 10) + parseInt(plus1 , 10) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/BLGLe/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function cal(){
    var plus = parseInt(document.getElementById('plus').value),
        plus1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('plus1').value);
    var x = plus + plus1;
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    if(result.value == ""){
     result.innerHTML = "?";
    }
    else{
     result.innerHTML = x;
    }
  }
</script>

<input type="text" id="plus" /> + <input type="text" id="plus1" /> = <span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? Didn't know a working solution could be downvoted.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you, but I'd like to answer your question. They probably did that because you didn't explain anything.

Comment: Right, and the guy who posted just this: " `var plus = parseInt(document.getElementById('plus').value, 10),
    plus1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('plus1').value, 10);`
This will do what you want." Got two upvotes. Looks a lot like what I posted.

Comment: Yea... he didn't explain either. At least the accepted answer did explain.